# how to generate .exe file using maven for RCP plugin project

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, exe, rcp

I have created one RCP Plugin project and converted it into maven project.
I have to generate .exe file for this project using maven.
The problem is that this RCP project not have main method.
Please share how to to do this.

Comment: [Eclipse Tycho](https://eclipse.org/tycho/) integrates with Maven to provide Eclipse build support.

Comment: @greg-449 the link you shared not provide any information about how to generate exe for RCP project

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorials at [the Code & Me blog](http://codeandme.blogspot.fr/2012/12/tycho-build-1-building-plug-ins.html). They take you from the basics of building a single plugin with Maven Tycho to building more complex artifacts such as products (which include the .exe), update sites and the like.

Comment: Thanks @S. Cambon But I have existing maven project that was created in Indigo version of eclipse and .exe should generate automatically whenever I build my maven project